# Google displaying incorrect title text in search results?

Tags: google-search

I googled my name (`justin lardinois`) and, unsurprisingly,  my in-development website, `justinlardinois.com`, came up in the search results.

But what's strange is the title text. The actual title text of my site's home page is `Justin Lardinois`, but Google displays it as `Schließen`, and offers to translate the page.

[image]

I don't have any code on my site than indicates a language, and there's certainly no German anywhere on it.

Comment: Have you considered that the domain might have been registered previously (prior to 2013) and Google may have crawled an earlier site with this title, but later was blocked by your _robots.txt_? If it's an issue, you could add a landing page (blank with just title and description meta) and then add an exception in your _robot.txt_ to allow crawling for just that page and submit it [here](http://www.google.com/submityourcontent/website-owner/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. This can be expected. There is a link to your site that Google followed therefor your site's home page is indexed regardless of the robots.txt file. It is something that Google has been doing for a while that many including myself do not agree with. There should be nothing indexed in any search engine that respects robots.txt.

Here is what Google says:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en

To quote:

> We use a number of different sources for this information, including
>   descriptive information in the title and meta tags for each page. We
>   may also use publicly available information—for instance, anchor text
>   or listings from the Open Directory Project (DMOZ)—or create rich
>   snippets based on markup on the page.

I agree that your site should not appear in the SERPs. But since it does and you do not allow search engines to access to your site by blocking it with robots.txt, they are not picking up your title tag or anything from your site at all. Instead, Google is picking a title for your site based upon some other resource.

The resource is likely:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Farchive.org%2Fstream%2Fdictionnairenobi00vors%2Fdictionnairenobi00vors_djvu.txt&ei=g6S8VNb8B5etyAS3_YCADA&usg=AFQjCNGQLGtdGVQGEN1irOnkqBtXCRseXA&sig2=hHyskgGVQn1-1KEO_aEEqw

...or...

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDwQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.loot.co.za%2Findex%2Fhtml%2Findex2379.html&ei=g6S8VNb8B5etyAS3_YCADA&usg=AFQjCNEAXVmJJW5vLlGaWuP3XU223pUoHQ&sig2=sbFC_hYD8rTipa2FwyLWRA

...or...

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2F194.97.159.218%2Fverlag%2Fahf%2Fhbo.php%3FF%3Dautoren%26T%3Dsuche%26buchstabe%3DJJastal&ei=g6S8VNb8B5etyAS3_YCADA&usg=AFQjCNF4eMbphgm8wh80SRpeNUpYWqa6VA&sig2=jOZCDqqHEDUn9N6jnMpB4g

...and so on where the word Schlieben can also be found.

If you search Google for *justin lardinois schlieben* you will find it.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware that Google still listed sites that have exclusionary `robots.txt` files, but I didn't understand why I was getting that title text. This cleared it up.

Comment: Anytime! We are here for you if you ever need us. There are some real experts on this site if you ever have any questions.